# Generating multiple water level scenarios with only DEM data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, water

I want to depict certain water level scenarios (from -0,40mNN to +0,20mNN) by using a two dimensional hypsometric map. Only provided data are DEM-files of the AOI.

I managed to create the hypsometric map, but how do I do the water level scenarios with only the DEM data?

I am using the desktop version of QGis (Version 3.10.5). Here is a picture of what the map should look like as a result:

[image]

Comment: I guess all you want is to colorcode your DEM from elevation -40 to 20 meters, and the rest should be transparent? You can achieve that simply by styling your DEM in QGIS without any analysis.

Comment: I have to create more than one map, so for each scenario one map.

Comment: Start with the highest scenario, colorcode everything from lowest value to 20, everything above 20 transparent. And then for every scenario duplicate layer, and adjust the transparency cutoff to the desired lower value. If you have 10 scenarios or less, it is few minutes job.

Comment: Thank you very much...would it be possible to explain the progress in detail? I´m actually just confused by dealing with the relief map and how to distribute the values...it has to do with the elevation somehow?

I have to create 10 scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only DEM as input, the most simple way is to style the DEM for the interval you need and mask (make transparent) everything above and/or below your desired interval. Then duplicate layer, and adjust colors for every scenario.

Example of styling - using Render type: Singleband pseudocolor on Band 1, set Min and Max to the values of your starting interval, and choose color ramp closest to what you like to see (you can adjust colors later). Then add one more value (green plus button), and set it tiny bit above your maximum interval of first scenario, e.g. maximum is 50, value for transparent color is 50.001.

[image: Example of styling raster]

You can set opacity (transparency) by double click on value and take down the opacity value to 0%. This way, as far as there is no higher value in color settings, starting 50.001 everything above will be transparent. Sure you can have multiple transparent intervals and many other variations, and simply adjust coloring of your duplicate. All depends how you set up your color value intervals.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! So if I got to depict water scenarios from -0.40mNN in 5cm steps to +0.20mNN, all I have to do is to set the min value to the according scenario (for example for the -0.40mNN scenario, I choose "-0.40" as Min-value) and then add the additional slightly increased value and make it transparent?

Comment: See my next answer, as I am not sure what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to visualize it you can create [contours](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#gdalcontour). I use 20 m intervals then applied a filter to the output line layer to only show 20, 40 and 60 m.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I already made this part for creating the relief map. I also operated with from lines to polygons. The result of my map should look something like this: (see answer below)

Comment: Edit your question and add any Picture you have

Comment: Ok sorry, done!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to show specific intervals in map, e.g. -0.40 to -0.35, -0.35 to - 0.30 all up to 0.15 to 0.20, the best way to get these intervals is to extract polygon contours from DEM raster.

From QGIS top menu use **Raster / Extraction / Contour...**

Set the interval to 0.05, open Advanced Parameters and into additional command-line parameters add -p (tool will create polygon contours instead of polyline contours). Also it is good idea to add columns for minimum and maximum elevation of interval so you can style/filter layer based on that.

```
-p -amin e_min -amax e_max
```

After vector polygon layer is created, you can filter content based on elevation (e_min) in Layer Properties / Settings - Provider Feature Filter to only interval (intervals) you want. E.g. Start Query Builder and type:

```
e_min > -0.40 and e_min < 0.20
```

Or you can achieve similar effect by just styling your layer - in Layer Properties on Symbology tap pick **Categorized** , as value pick e_min and add only one value (or multiple values) you want to see:

[image]